# Ropes suspended from moving objects are not straight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

If I were to pilot a jet and steer it so it circles a point, and then I lowered a box of supplies from the jet on a string, why wouldn't the string fall perfectly straight from the jet?

I.e. why do objects suspended by inextensible string from accelerating vehicles not hang directly under the vehicle, but rather "lag" behind them?

Comment: Hint: objects hanging from vehicles **that are not accelerating** do hang straight downwards (ignoring air resistance). Ask yourself if a jet flying in a circle is accelerating or not.

Comment: @JohnRennie It is accelerating. Now please, help me

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I don't get it, air resistance causes it to "lag"? How?

Comment: Because [inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia)?

Answer (score 1):

This is of the same reason that a passenger feels pressed to the side in a car while turning.

Consider what happens if the jet suddenly vanishes. The box would stop it's circle motion and continue straight (seen from above). This means, it would move out of the circle, it is being kept in.

And that's the thing. The box wants to keep it's straight path (straight seen from above), but it can't and is forced to turn constantly. But it still wants to, so it stays as far out as possible.

The heavier the box, the larger is the (horizontal) force required to cause the acceleration needed for the box to do the turning. Hanging straight down, there is not much force horizontally. The more angle the rope gets, the more sideways force there is. At some point there is enough to balance it all; and this *will* be at some angle - not straight vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the rope (assumed as having no bending stiffness and thus transmitting only forces but no moments) will extend exactly in the direction of the applied force, if we ignore aerodynamic forces on the rope. If the object that the rope is attached to is accelerating, then in an inertial reference frame there are two forces: One is the gravitational force, directed straight downwards (towards the gravitational center of the Earth), and the other one is the force that is necessary to accelerate the object. The total force is the vector sum of the two forces. If the acceleration is not parallel to the gravitational force, then the resulting force will not be straight up, but at an angle. You might want to make yourself a little sketch if this is not immediately clear to you.

Comment: Is it a pseudo force that causes the acceleration? Aren't you confusing it with the pseudo force called "centrifugal force"?

Comment: No. Notice that I intentionally specified an inertial frame of reference.

Comment: I noticed. In that case it seems that the tension in the rope is called a pseudo force. That is not correct. It is an actual present force.

Comment: @Steeven: Oops, I'm sorry, I now see that I had called the force a "pseudo-force", which is incorrect. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The box of supplies is moving in a horizontal circle, therefore accelerating towards the centre of that circle. So there must be a net force on the box acting towards the centre of the circle, horizontally. If the rope was vertical there could be no horizontal component of force. The rope has to be at an angle in order to provide a horizontal component of force on the box.

See [Does a rope connecting an object to a constant-velocity aircraft fly at an angle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285405)

Answer (score -1):

There are two forces at play here. Gravity and air drag.

If drag is constant throughout the rope then the two forces are combined producing a certain "loading angle" on which the total loading is applied.

Now the problem becomes the same as a hanging string with the centenary shape as a solution, but instead of vertical being along gravity it is along the loading direction.

In this local coordinate system the solution of the curve is of this form

$$y(x) = y_c + a \left( \cosh \left( \frac{x-x_c}{a} \right) -1 \right)$$

where $(x_c,y_c)$ are the lowest point on the curve, and $a$ is the catenary constant (measured in length units). For a string of linear mass $\lambda = \frac{{\rm d}m}{{\rm d}x}$ the catenary constant is $$a = \frac{H}{g \lambda}$$ where $H$ is horizontal tension of the string.

Answer (score -2):

The answer lie in your question.In this case the acceleration of the jet is non uniform.so if the jet is turned around a certain point, then there is already a force which is centre-seeking.so if you hang a rope from the jet,the rope experience a centre fleeing force,just like a bus turned around a path,the passenger experience a force that is centre fleeing in nature.

Comment: But they don't. There is no force acting outwards.

Comment: You previously said that the jet are accelerating .then how can u definitely argue that there is no force acting outwards???Please explain your argument...

Comment: The jet is accelerating inwards. The jet is being acted upon by an upwards lift force and an inwards centripetal force. That is all. And its weight. But no outwards force.

Comment: Then what are the forces that balance this centripetal force?You said an inward centripetal force is present but no outward force!!!Strange Very Strange!!!If there is a centripetal force then there must be a centrifugal force which is centre fleeing and directing outwards in practical sense...Is not it!!!Think carefully!!!

Comment: @Steeven do you mean centrifugal force is a pseudo force? To the best of my knowledge, centripetal force does exist, normally because of tension in the string or gravity etc.

Comment: @theonlygusti Ahh, damn, sorry, that is a typo. I've deleted that comment and rewritten correctly here below. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I will have to agree with @theonlygusti here. There is no outwards force. The "centrifugal force" is a pseudo force (a fictitious force). It is not a force that exists, just the feeling of the body's tendency to fall out of the circle. "Then what are the forces that balance this centripetal force?" The centripetal force (applied from the rope) is not balanced - otherwise there wouldn't be any acceleration inwards.

Comment: That means you assume the frame a inertial reference frame.where centripetal force is present but centrifugal force is absent..okk...but previously @theonlygusti said that the jet is accelerating..that means the frame is a rotatating reference frame or non inertial reference frame.so centrifugal force must be present on that frame.@theonlygusti you ask that why wouldn't the string fall perfectly from the jet...you must also consider coriolis force which is also a fictitious force  when you drop a body above from the earth surface...